# If the People's Palace and D'Hara are in new England, then where is the Imperial Order?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

This is something that's confused me. In one of the books in the Sword of Truth series, I believe Faith of the Fallen, someone shows that the Imperial Order is huge in comparison to the D'Haran Empire, to the tune of hundreds of times larger.

then, in Confessor, Richard duplicates the world and gives the people the choice to go to that world. Over half of the population goes there. It is implied that this world is basically our current world.

Then, in Law of Nines, a spinoff of the Sword of Truth series, I remember Alex Rahl finding what remains of the People's Palace in New England. However, this doesn't really match the map given in the books:

[image]

According to this map, there's a body of water at one side, but that doesn't match the area. Either it's the Atlantic, which doesn't fit with the scale of the Old World, or it is the Fleuve Saint-Laurent, but that wouldn't quite fit with Law of Nines, because I remember it not just being New England, but Maine.

The biggest reason it doesn't fit, though, is the distances. According to Stone of Tears, Richard needed weeks to get from People's Palace to Aydindril, even on horseback. I can't see it taking weeks to get from one side of New England to another, even on foot.

Am I just reading too much into these different plots? has Terry Goodkind simply written himself into a corner with his decriptions? or is there a better explanation? I've done some personal research, and I figured that a better fit would be either Anatolia as the New World and the rest of Asia as the Old World, or current Israel/Lebanon/Syria/Jordan as the New World and Africa as the Old world.

Is the continuity in the main Sword of Truth series and the Spinoff series not intended to be consistent with each other concerning location?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think this is just inconsistency on the part of the author. Either that or the area is much larger than just New England (say, like, the entire eastern US). Either way, I think Goodkind flubbed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of how Richard explained how he created the other world. The piece of folded cloth and the blot of ink. One drop of ink creates a mark on opposite ends of the fabric. So if you follow the logic of the ink blot, both marks would not be exact but instead similar and corresponding attributes (not to mention mirror images of each other).

So if you make the assumption that Orden followed Richards idea of how the cloth/ink blot duplicates itself, it would make perfect sense the lands would be different but similar. Then add in how the chimes may have altered the land and very fabric of reality in this new world as it purged magic from it.

For that matter, who's to say some level of magic wasn't holding the tectonic plates in stasis and the loss of that kind of potential spell could have far reaching effects (possibly an effect of the great barrier, which if the world shifted over the millenia the barrier might become ineffective in time).

Answer (score 1):

In the law of nines, it states that this world is the world  that was created, but that it also needed a link between the two. So, the people's palace in this world isn't actually the people's palace. It's just a rock formation that looks similar in design and layout. This world isn't the future, it's a completely different world and the people's palace is a rock formation that serves as a link from this world to the other.